# Cannot logout from Keycloak using Rest Endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

When I am trying to logout using rest endpoint from Keycloak server it is not working.
I am using Keycloak version 15.0.

I am trying the following:

```
POST http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/javatechbd/protocol/openid-connect/logout

Authorization: Bearer token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=my-client-id&client_secret=my-client-secret&refresh_token: my-refresh-token
```

It responses with 203 but it does not invalidate the token

Comment: Please prove statement "it does not invalidate the token".

Comment: Which token - access or refresh?
Access tokens do not get invalidated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When I check it in keycloak administration console, the session is still valid. This way I can say that the user session is not yet invalidated, although I called logout endpoint with response code 204